# Grafana loki: Does it support Amazon Keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, amazon-keyspaces, grafana-loki

Does anyone try to config Grafana Loki using Amazon Keyspaces for index and AWS S3 for chunk storage?
I keep getting protocol version mismatch error.

Answer (score 1):

After researching for few hours i got it running. So the issue was basically host SSL verification, which set true by default.

The below configs works perfectly with aws keyspace + loki docker grafana/loki:master-1664a98 and Cassandra config

```
    client_configs+: {
     cassandra+: {
       consistency: 'LOCAL_QUORUM',
       port: 9142,
       host_verification: false,
       disable_initial_host_lookup: false,
       SSL: true,
       timeout: "60s",
       connect_timeout: "3m0s"
     }
    },
```

You can choose LOCAL_ONE as consistency as per your demand.